# Select the rows where the Tier value is different than the previous row. Sorted by Account # and Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wanting to select a value from a table in SQL Server only where there is actually a change from the previous vale in the table. Example below:

Assume the below is named Table A:

```
Account #     Tier     Date
10000         1        1/1/2020
10000         1        1/2/2020
10000         1        1/3/2020
10000         2        2/1/2020
10000         2        2/2/2020
10000         3        3/1/2020
10000         2        4/1/2020
```

I want to return the below:

```
Account #     Tier     Date
10000         1        1/1/2020
10000         2        2/1/2020
10000         3        3/1/2020
10000         2        4/1/2020
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing someone did because the question is vague - what is a `change from the previous value`? Rows 1 and 2 in your sample data have different dates, so that's a change, right? So shouldn't row 2 be in the output? Another way to ask would be, "When this data set is sorted by account # and then date, I want to select the rows where the `Tier` value is different than the `Tier` value of the previous row."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [LAG](http://sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/) window function to compare the value in a column with the previous row's value. You need to supply `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` arguments so the window function knows what row should be the *previous* row as far as the comparison is concerned. In this example, the partition is the `Account #` column and the order by is the `date` column. If the value of the `tier` column is different between the current row and the previous row, then the row is included in the output. [Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a35cce/6)

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(Tier) OVER (PARTITION BY [Account #] ORDER BY date) LastTier 
    FROM @t 
)
SELECT cte.[Account #],
       cte.Tier,
       cte.Date
FROM cte 
WHERE cte.Tier <> cte.LastTier OR cte.LastTier IS NULL
```

Comment: Avoiding functions in the where clause predicate would assist performance, suggest `OR cte.lastTier IS NULL' instead of using `ISNULL` on both side of a predicate.

Comment: @Used_By_Already . . . There are many good reasons to avoid `ISNULL()`.  However, performance in this case is probably not one of them because the query needs to do a full table scan *anyway*.  And as a built-in function, `iSNULL` should have very low overhead.  That said, don't ever use `ISNULL()` because there is a perfectly fine STANDARD SQL construct, `IS NULL`.

Comment: This worked and I updated the subject line as you suggested as well. Thank you so much for your help!